# mvc4 actionlink image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to replace the infamous "your logo here" in _Layout.cshtml for the ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application. The following works (works as in the image is displayed) for the main page (Home view) but not on the contact view (no image but the action works). I need this to work both in the development environment as well as the production environment.

```
< p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", new
  {
  style = "background: url('./Images/login_sm.bmp') no-repeat center right;
          display:block; height:84px; width:264px;"
  })
</ p>
```

Comment: what you mean with it doesn't work, image does not appear? it appears but clicking doesn't send you anywhere? it appears unaligned?

Comment: There is no picture on subsequent pages. The clicking still works. I am assuming that it isn't finding the image. The html when viewing source looks identical (as I would expect)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Images are always relative to the location of the current CSS.

If you are using inline CSS you should use url helpers:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    " ", 
    "Index", 
    "Home", 
    null , 
    new { 
        style = "background: url('" + Url.Content("~/images/login_sm.bmp") + "') no-repeat center right; display:block; height:84px; width:264px;" 
    }
)
```

or if you decide to define a CSS class:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    " ", 
    "Index", 
    "Home",  
    null , 
    new { 
        @class = "mylink" 
    }
)
```

where you have defined the `.mylink` rule in `~/content/Site.css`:

```
.mylink {
    background: url('../images/login_sm.bmp') no-repeat center right; 
    display: block; 
    height: 84px; 
    width: 264px;
}
```

Comment: Thx! I used the first method. I knew I was doing something stupid. I tried URL.Content in different ways but obviously not the correct way.

Comment: Is it a good practice to pass a " " as the linkText? Isn't it considered as a hack?

Answer (score 12):

The best way you can do as below

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home").ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/assets/img/logo.png\" ... />"))
```

which perfectly working

Comment: It does, but unfortunately the image is highlighted. How to remove this?

Comment: @user2609980 I do not have such problem . may be its your css problem . kindly check it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was indeed something in the CSS. Since it is a normal link and all my links were highlighted this also showed up in around the logo image. I removed i and now it looks nice. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @user2609980 Feeling good by knowing you reached at the correct solutions.

Comment: That was great;however, styling the image was kind of tricky because of this character '\'. But figured it out: <img class=\"logo\"

Comment: @usefulBee Thanks for your attention . You are right but once you start to use , It will be fine . I will update also as per your suggestion.

Comment: Can this be put into a custom helper, something like: public static MvcHtmlString AddImage(this MvcHtmlString html, string imagePath) { return Html.Raw(Html.ToHtmlString().Replace("{0}", imagePath)); }  <--doesn't compile so obviously I'm approaching this wrong

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
<a href='@Url.Action("action", "Controller")'>
<img src='@Url.Content("~/images/imageName.png")' /></a>
```

this is working fine and it works similar to `@Html.ActionLink("linkName","action","Controller")`

Answer (score 1):

I edited Dilip0165 solution a little

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home").ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"" + @Url.Content("~/Content/assets/img/logo.png") + "\" alt=\"Link description\" title=\"Link description\" />"))
```

If you want it without default border, add this to your css

```
img {border: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when required high level of `<a>` tag customization (e.g. other tags inside anchor), it is better to do it yourself.

I was using UrlHelper.GenerateUrl method for generating URL, and then I manually created `<a>` tag and used generated URL.